# Nuxtjs multi-step-form validations needs to be popped-up when clicking on the nuxt-link button using vee-validate

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vee-validate, nuxtjs

I'have separate components for all my pages to be navigated one after another if required fields are filled if not I should get all error messages as a pop-up if the required fields are not filled.

We have used vee-validate library to display all the errors it is working fine, when we actually focusing on the input and not-filling it, we are able to see the error message, but when we are not focusing and directly clicking continue, I am not seeing any errors

```html
    <template>
    <section>
      <ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ invalid }">
                <form class="text-left">
                  <div>
                    <select
                      class="form-control w-25"
                      v-model="name1"
                      v-on:change="saveData($event)"
                    >
                      <option value="0">Please select</option>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <ValidationProvider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
                  <div>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      v-model="firstName"
                      v-on:change="saveData($event)"
                      id="fname"
                    />
                    <span style="color: red; font-Weight: bold; font-size: 12px">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                  </div>
                  </ValidationProvider>
                  <ValidationProvider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">                  
                  <div class="pb-2 pt-2">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      v-model="lastName"
                      v-on:change="saveData($event)"                      
                      id="lname"
                      placeholder
                    />
                    <span style="color: red; font-Weight: bold; font-size: 12px">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                  </div>
                  </ValidationProvider>
                </form>
                </ValidationObserver>
              <footer></footer>
           </section>       
</template>

    <script>
      import {ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver} from 'vee-validate';
      import footer from '@component/footer'; 

    components :{
        ValidationProvider,
        ValidationObserver,
        footer
    }
      methods:{
          saveData(event){
              console.log(event)
          }
      }
  </script>
```

** Footer Component **
I have used validationObserver with refs also but, not able to trigger .validate()

```html
<template>
    <section>
    <b-row>
    <b-col>
        <nuxt-link v-if="continueToNextPage() != 'null'" class="applyContinue" :to="continueToNextPage()">Continue</nuxt-link>
      </b-col>
    </b-row> 
    </section>   
</template>

<script>
export default {
methods: {
    continueToNextPage(){
        this.$refs.validate()
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Can you please help us in resolving this issue!

Answer (score 0):

The `footer` component doesn't have access to its parent's ref so you cannot validate from there, instead let it emit a `continue` event and have the parent listen for it and trigger validation accordingly.

**footer.vue**

```
<template>
    <section>
    <b-row>
    <b-col>
        <nuxt-link v-if="continueToNextPage() != 'null'" class="applyContinue" :to="continueToNextPage()">Continue</nuxt-link>
      </b-col>
    </b-row> 
    </section>   
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    continueToNextPage(){
      this.$emit('continue');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And the parent component:

```
<ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ invalid }">
  <!-- .... -->
</ValidationObserver>

<footer @continue="$refs.form.validate()"></footer>
```